# How do I prevent strange escape chars from appearing on prompt

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I am using Cygwin on windows 7
mintty 2.3.6 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)

And randomly a [28~ will appear on my prompt line. Sometimes it even appears while I am in the middle of typing a command. And often it appears even when the terminal window doesn't have focus.

This is really hard to google for, because google just sees the 28. I would appreciate suggestions on how to improve my google-fu to search for the specific sequence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code . Have you redefined the PS1 or TERM setting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by an application such as Caffeine, which stops your screensaver by pressing a key periodically (like F15 which has ansi sequence `\[[28~`) .  You can stop the program or add an entry in your ~/.inputrc to ignore the sequence.  in ~/.inputrc add the line:

`"\e[28~":""`

to remap F15 to nothing in the terminal.

Comment: Perfect. This makes a lot of sense. And I had no idea that was how Caffeine was implemented. Thanks! it was driving me nuts.

Comment: So it was Caffeine?  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, there are two other ways to fix this:

1. Prevent F15 from being interpreted on the mintty side: Add the following line to your mintty config file (e.g. `~/.minttyrc`). It tells mintty to ignore F15 by itself or with the Ctrl modifier, which does the trick for me (on my machine, it would produce `~` by itself, and with Ctrl, `;5~`):

   ```
   KeyFunctions=F15:void;C+F15:void
   ```
2. Prevent Caffeine from sending F15 by running it with the `-useshift` option.